# Is bitwise complement of (n-1) equals to (-n)

Tags: c++, bit, xor

The following code prints the two odd occuring numbers in an array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   int arr[n],x=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cin>>arr[i];
      x=x^arr[i];
   }
   x=(x&~(x-1));
   int reso=0,rest=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(x&arr[i])
         reso=reso^arr[i];
      else
         rest=rest^arr[i];
   }
   cout<<reso<<' '<<rest;
   return 0;
}
```

I observed that ~(x-1)==(-x) in 2's complement hence I replaced the ~(x-1) with (-x) and wrote the following code, which worked fine :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   int arr[n],x=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cin>>arr[i];
      x=x^arr[i];
   }
   x=(x&(-x)); //changed expression
   int reso=0,rest=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(x&arr[i])
         reso=reso^arr[i];
      else
         rest=rest^arr[i];
   }
   cout<<reso<<' '<<rest;
   return 0;
}
```

So I need help, is ~(x-1) is equal to (-x) in 2's complement or I am misconcluding here, kindly provide explanation ?

Comment: I’m slightly confused by your title. Would I be correct to read  “(bitwise). complement” for “negation”.

Comment: Complement is not negation. Your title and your code are mututally contradictory.

Comment: And there is no [tag:bitset] here. Please clarify your question.

Comment: 1. "Is negation of `(n-1)` equal to `(-n)`": no. 2. "Is `~(x-1)` equal to `(-x)`": yes, in twos-complement arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the 1's complement of a d-1 digits number is the same as subtracting it from the number 111...1 (d-1) digits, which is 2^d-1.

E.g. with five bits numbers,

```
9d = 01001b; ~9d = 10110b = -16d + 6d = -10d
```

and

```
-9d = -16d + 6d = 11010b
```

Comment: That is 2's compliment you are (correctly) describing.